# 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage' doesn't loaded correctly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing an OPC Client, everything was good until i get an HRESULT-FAULT Error, so i try this solution; [error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2013/03/08/error-hresult-e-fail-has-been-returned-from-a-call-to-a-com-component.aspx)

I execute this command :

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe  /setup
```

Then when trying to lunch VisualStudio V12 i get this error:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error says:
"The package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.SolutionNavigatorPackage' was not loaded correctly.

The problem could be due to a modification of the configuration or the installation of another extension. For further informations, look at the file 'C:\Users\Student\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ActivityLog.xml'.

Do you want to show this error message again?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the persons who have the same problem:

I solve this problem by Uninstall then install Visual Studio 2012.